# looking through the columns and highlighting the row.

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet "Data" and I am having the columns from G to P filled with Price. I have another column U in the same sheet which has the maximum price. (target price).

I now, would like to check through each rows, and if any one of the column between G to P has an price more than the target price in my column U, then I want to highlight the complete row with red.

I tried a code like below, but it dint work. Can anyone suggest, how I can look into each of the column and compare to the target and highlight. It would be great if you can comment the lines of your code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Integer

For i = 7 To 16
    If Cells(Target.Row, 21).Value <= Cells(Target.Row, i).Value Then
        Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next i

For i = 7 To 16
    If Cells(Target.Row, 21).Value > Cells(Target.Row, i).Value Then
        Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
Next i

    If Cells(Target.Row, 22).Value = "x" Then
        Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need VBA to achieve this. You may use Conditional Formatting for that.

Comment: @sktneer I would like to do with vba ,Could you help please

Comment: You can define/alter conditional formatting built in Excel using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I would still do this with the help of conditional formatting though applied through VBA as you insisted.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range
If Target.Row >= 7 And Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:P")) Is Nothing Then
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("G7:U" & lr)
    With rng
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
            "=AND(ROW($G7)>=7,G7<>"""",$U7<>"""",MAX($G7:$P7)>=$U7)"
        .FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 65535
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't find any changes when I type in the value, it remains the same

Comment: The code will track any changes you make in columns G:P starting from Row7.

Comment: And even if you make the changes as I described above, make sure that the corresponding cell in column P is not empty. Since the code is comparing the inputs from column G:P with the input in corresponding cells in column P, it will only compare if the column P is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Cells(Target.Row, 22).Value = "x" Or Application.Max(Target.Rows) < Cells(Target.Row, 21) Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = xlNone
    Else
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
End Sub
```